# What do these 2 symbols mean

Tags: meaning

I'd love to know what these symbols mean if you have any idea. Thank you very much. [image]

Comment: You really shouldn't get a tattoo if you don't know what it means

Comment: Also, [we don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: I think the calligraphy in the picture is bad

Answer (score 3):

It looks like 焦点 (pronounced 'shо̄ten'), meaning 'focus' or 'focal point'.

[image]

Comment: Which honestly sounds pretty lame as a tattoo. The person who got the tattoo might have been trying to translate ‘focus’ (mental) into Japanese but this is definitely not the right way to do that.